# Posterior distribution of an 'exponentiated' version of a Dirichlet-categorical model

Tags: probability-distributions

Maximum a posteriori estimates can be approached by sampling from an 'exponentiated' version of the posterior. That is, samples from $p_\eta(\theta \mid x) \propto p(\theta \mid x)^\eta$ approach the MAP estimate as $\eta\to\infty$. 
I was wondering what would happen if you introduced this $\eta\ge1$ in the following Dirichlet-categorical model:
\begin{align}
(\theta_1, \dots, \theta_K) &\sim \text{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_K) \\
x &\sim \text{Categorical}(\hat{\theta}_1, \dots, \hat{\theta}_K), 
\quad \text{where } \hat{\theta}_k = \frac{\theta_k^\eta}{\sum_{j=1}^K \theta_j^\eta}.
\end{align}
I am mainly interested in the posterior $p(\boldsymbol\theta \mid x)$. 
For $\eta=1$ this is a Dirichlet with parameters $\boldsymbol\alpha + \boldsymbol c$ if $\boldsymbol c$ is the vector of counts; i.e. $c_k =  \mathbb{1}(x = k)$. But for $\eta>1$ I think it is not a Dirichlet, because the normalizing 'constant' $\bigl(\sum_j \theta_j^\eta\bigr)^{-1}$ of the categorical depends on $\boldsymbol \theta$:

$$
p(\boldsymbol \theta \mid x) 
\propto p_\eta(x \mid \boldsymbol\theta) \cdot p(\boldsymbol\theta)
\propto \frac{\theta_x^\eta}{\sum_{j=1}^K \theta_j^\eta} 
  \cdot \prod_{k=1}^K \theta_k^{\alpha_k - 1}
= \Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^K \theta_j^\eta\Bigr)^{-1} 
  \cdot \prod_{k=1}^K \theta_k^{\alpha_k + \eta c_k - 1}.
$$

But what is it, if anything? Concretely, I have two questions:

1. Is this a know distribution?
2. If not, is it possible to compute the normalising constant $\int_\Delta \bigl(\sum_j \theta_j^\eta\bigr)^{-1} \prod_k \theta^{\alpha_k + \eta c_k - 1} d\boldsymbol\theta$, with $\Delta$ being the simplex?
   I have no idea if there is anything you can do with the sum and all suggestions (including 'probably not') would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

(I believe it is also kind of intuitive *that* the posterior is not Dirichlet. As $\eta \to \infty$ you tend to get $x = \text{argmax}_k \theta_k$. After observing $x$ there is only one part of the simplex where $\boldsymbol\theta$ could have lain: $S_x=\{\boldsymbol\theta \in \Delta: \theta_x \ge \theta_k, \forall k\}$. So the posterior would be $p(\boldsymbol\theta \mid x) = p(\boldsymbol\theta \mid \boldsymbol\theta \in S_x)$, which looks like the prior restricted to $S_x$. That sounds pretty discontinuous and un-Dirichlet-ish to me — right?)